# Existing column can't be found by DataFrame#filter in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark to perform SparkSQL on my Hive tables.

```
records = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

which retrieves the contents of the table.

When I use the filter argument as a string, it works okay:

```
records.filter("field_i = 3")
```

However, when I try to use the filter method, as documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter)

```
records.filter(records.field_i == 3)
```

I am encountering this error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.filter.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attributes field_i missing from field_1,field_2,...,field_i,...field_n
```

eventhough this field_i column clearly exists in the DataFrame object.

I prefer to use the second way because I need to use Python functions to perform record and field manipulations.

I am using Spark 1.3.0 in Cloudera Quickstart CDH-5.4.0 and Python 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

From [Spark DataFrame documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframe-operations)

> In Python it’s possible to access a DataFrame’s columns either by attribute (df.age) or by indexing (df['age']). While the former is convenient for interactive data exploration, users are highly encouraged to use the latter form, which is future proof and won’t break with column names that are also attributes on the DataFrame class.

It seems that the name of your field can be a reserved word, try with:

```
records.filter(records['field_i'] == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to upgrade my Spark from 1.3.0 to 1.4.0 in Cloudera Quick Start CDH-5.4.0 and the second filtering feature works. Although I still can't explain why 1.3.0 has problems on that.

Comment: When i get this error , I sometimes use df.reset_index() function and it seems to work for me . I usually find this error when i do some tranmsformations and then try to access the column